# How to get credentials from url in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to retrieve user and password from the url http://user:password@domain.com using nginx but I cannot find these variables name in nginx documentation or google.
Is there anyway to achieve this or to get the url that the user has truly typed in his browser ( i.e. http://user:password@domain.com ) ?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side. There is `$remote_user` variable, but there is no variable for password.

Comment: My understanding of $remote_user is that basic auth must be processed by nginx first, what I want is just to retrieve the user and password parts of an url ( I'd like to use them for rewriting )

Comment: Browsers don't send them as you see it in addess bar. Instead they send `Authorization` header. So you'll have to manually process that header (e.g. with embedded lua/perl or external script)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm going to try this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in fact my problem was related to the fact that my browser (FireFox) seems to not handle request like http://user:password@domain.com anymore.
I have tried curl and nginx successfully pass user and password to php.

Answer (score 0):

@user1723580 The basic authentication in URL is working fine in Firefox event on the latest Nightly version.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete this, and add it as a comment when you have enough reputation.